# Creating base64 encoded JPG string from image from camera for upload

Tags: android, image, paperclip, arrays, jpeg

I am building an Android app that takes photos, then uploads them to a Rails API.

The api expects the base64 encoded raw file bytes, to be stored as a temp file representing the image in JPG format.

However, the API is rejecting the uploaded file with this error message:

```
<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:
```

This seems to be due to a failure of encoding on the part of the Android app.

The base64 image bytes that I'm sending up look like this:
[image: log output]

Which appears invalid just by looking at it.

The image is created in android by taking a pic with the Camera API and base64 encoding the resulting byteArray:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You could try NO_WRAP instead of DEFAULT, Android's Base64 implementation adds wrapping by default.

Comment: what is wrapping out of curiousity?

Comment: You can check the docs, NO_WRAP just ensures there are no line terminators added to the output value, which may be the cause you can't decode the value into a valid Bitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On button click for capturing an image from a camera use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and on activityResult of the activity implement the following code:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
final ImageView uploadArea = (ImageView) attachmentDialog.findViewById(R.id.uploadArea);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                    matrix.postRotate(-90);

                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] attachmentBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    String attachmentData = Base64.encodeToString(attachmentBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);


                    uploadArea.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "CTSTemp" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
```

I hope this will help you, and for any farther info, please ask